# Angular4: how to pass data to another component using router navigate?

Tags: angular, parameters, angular2-routing, router

I'm developing an Angular2 app and I would like to navigate from a component to another one passing some data. In my case I need to pass a configuration object that I use in the component that I navigate to for changing some behaviours according to that configuration object.

```
private goToOtherComponent(): void {
    let options = {
        checkboxes: true,
        actions: ['save', 'close'],
        items: ['foo', 'bar'],
        clickable: false
    };

    this.route.navigate(['documents'], options)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('response', response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('error', error);
        });
}
```

I have read some questions like mine and I have read Angular documentation, but I can't figure out how to do that.

- `RouteParams` is deprecated
- `queryParams` is not what I'm looking for
- `RouteSegment` I think is not suitable for my case
- Using a shared service is a solution I do not like

Here is how I pass data in the `routing` ngModule file:

```
{path: 'documents', data: { someValue: 'foo', otherValue: 'bar' }
```

I would like to have a similar way to pass data using `navigate` method.
Then how to retrieve that `options` object in the component that I navigate to?

Comment: Use a shared service like explained in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Why I had to use a shared service? Can't I pass data such as I do in the routing file? (Please read again my question, I have updated it)

Comment: No, that's only for resolvers and `data` in routes config. If you want to dynamically pass data between components that are not direct parent and child (or siblings) you need a shared service. Dynamically added components are never considered child of any component in this regard.

Comment: It's not a "dynamically added component" the component I want to navigate to. It is a component that is defined in the routing file and in the app module. I just want to load it with some data. I can't understand why I can pass data from routing paths and I can't do the same using `navigate`. I'm looking for something similar to `RouteParams`... that is deprecated. What can I use as substitute?

Comment: The router dynamically adds the component depending on the active route. The router uses `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` to add the component, therefore the components added by the router are simply a dynamically added components.

Comment: Do you know why I can pass data in the routing paths and I can't do that using `navigate` ?

Comment: @smartmouse I think your problem is related to: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8515, if you don't want to use queryParams because it shows your data in the url, you need to do it with a shared service as Günter said.

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your support ;)